# mutter-rounded gets misconfigured when system updates

Tags: mutter

Every time that I have an update or upgrade on Ubuntu 22.04, mutter-rounded gets misconfigured, and I have to re-install it for it to work.

I go to the installation process stated on GitHub, but every time I have to update and upgrade the kernel, mutter-rounded gets misconfigured and I have to do the whole process again.  Is this normal, I think not, but is there a fix to it?

```
gjs:26284): Gjs-CRITICAL **: 23:13:23.807: JS ERROR: Error: GSettings key clip-edge-padding not found in schema org.gnome.mutter
_checkKey@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:580:23
createCheckedMethod/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:532:30
@dist/mutter_settings.js:1:22437
@dist/mutter_settings.js:1:27804
@dist/mutter_settings.js:1:27808


(gjs:26284): Gjs-CRITICAL **: 23:13:23.807: Script dist/mutter_settings.js threw an exception
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and post a link to the github repo?

Comment: @Nmath, My question is why is it that mutter-rounded gets misconfigured once I updated and upgraded ubuntu 22.04 repositories?  Now to give you more on the subject for a newbie like myself is impossible.  The code that I placed above is the mutter-rounded-setting, which throws when I try to configure it again, so I have to reinstall mutter-rounded all over again.

Comment: @Nmath, my explanation is very simple.  I install mutter-rounded on Ubunutu 22.04 and install mutter-rounded-setting.  Now, when the system updates and upgrades, mutter-rounded-setting can't be accessed, and the blur configuration for the Terminal, and the applications that were configured on mutter-rounded-setting, get misconfigured.  I get the message above when I try to get access to the mutter-rounded setting.  Now more than that I can't tell you since is all I can convey from what the terminal spit out.  I appreciate your philosophical statements I will consider them in my upcoming book.

Comment: @Nmath, thank you very much.  I figured it out.  I thank you since your first message was very clear on the documentation part.  You're right I need to read my documentaiton very well before any installation is made.